# SSL/https setup for herokuapp.com address rather than my actual domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, heroku, dreamhost

I have a subdomain of my site pointed to a rails app at mysite.herokuapp.com. I bought a certificate from godaddy and seem to have that all set up correctly. So that when I go to:

```
http://mysite.herokuapp.com or
http://dev.mysite.com
```

it's redirected to:

```
https://mysite.herokuapp.com or
https://dev.mysite.com
```

The problem is that when I visit dev.mysite.com, I get the error: Safari can't verify the identity of the website. But when I go to mysite.herokuapp.com, I don't get the error. I wanted this to be set up the other way, so that dev.mysite.com did not cause the error.

I'm not sure where I went wrong. I used dev.mysite.com when generating the key and when setting it up at godaddy.com. Any ideas where I should look?

P.S. The old site is hosted at dreamhost and the DNS info is stored there as well. So I created a subdomain there of type cname which points to mysite.herokuapp.com.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [install your SSL certificate at Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl).

The very abbreviated process is:

```
heroku addons:add ssl
heroku certs:add server.crt server.key
```

Comment: Ty for the response. I did that as well. The https serving is working at Heroku, just for the wrong domain.

Comment: If you already did that, you should [contact Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/support-channels) for further assistance.